# How to show translation text in angularjs controller alert from json file?

Tags: json, angularjs, angular-translate

I have a JSON file with translations, like this one:

```
"ALERT_MESSAGE" : "Select a row"
```

Now, I want to show an alert from my controller when the user try to access to a link without select a row.

```
$scope.goToNext = function () {
    if($scope.isSelected === false){
        alert("What should I put here?");
    }
    else{
        Navigator.goTo("/next", {
            back: "/previus",
            asd: $scope.asd
        });
    }
};
```

How can I use my translations file on the controller?

Comment: Are you using some specific Angular module to handle translations? If not take a look at [angular-translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/).

Comment: I need to have all the translations on the same file, and access to it's content on the controller like on html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally adding $filter to the controller and using it like here:

```
alert($filter('translate')('ALERT_MSG'));
```

Comment: Since it seems you were able to resolve your problem perhaps you could include more details in your answer in order for other people to also benefit from it in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is using the `$translate` service itself (if you are using angular-translate ;))

```
alert($translate.instant('ALERT_MSG'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Following function will show the changed language:

```
 $scope.translateLangText=function(text){
             $scope.$watch(
                    function() { return $filter('translate')(text); },
                     function(newval) { alert(newval); }
                 );
             }

$scope.translateLangText('Hello');
```